# Getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProvider')" when creating a checkout session with Firebase and Stripe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm encountering an issue when trying to create a checkout session in my Firebase and Stripe integration. I keep getting the error message "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProvider')" in my code.

This is the code that's responsible for creating the checkout

```
const {
  createCheckoutSession,
  getStripePayments,
} = require("@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments");
const { getFunctions, httpsCallable } = require("@firebase/functions");
const app = require("../firebase/init.js");

const payments = getStripePayments(app, {
  productsCollection: "products",
  customersCollection: "customers",
});

const loadCheckout = async (priceId) => {
  await createCheckoutSession(payments, {
    price: priceId,
    success_url: window.location.origin,
    cancel_url: window.location.origin,
  })
    .then((snapshot) => window.location.assign(snapshot.url))
    .catch((error) => console.warn(error));
};

const goToBillingPortal = async () => {
  const instance = getFunctions(app, "europe-west");
  const functionRef = httpsCallable(
    instance,
    "ext-firestore-stripe-payments-createPortalLink"
  );

  await functionRef({
    returnUrl: `${window.location.origin}/account`,
  })
    .then(({ data }) => window.location.assign(data.url))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
};

module.exports = { loadCheckout, goToBillingPortal, payments };
```